# Listbox Updating in Scheduling Application

Tags: vb.net

I am currently making a Scheduler application in vb.net which looks like the image shown below. I wanted the data to be fetched from the table so in the `listbox` property i added `datasource` as the table name binding source and in display member page the attribute of that table. Look in the image on the right and when I press that add button the entries what I have written is saved in database but is not reflected back in the `listbox` hope you understand my problem.Please Help! Add button Code:

```
  db5.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Final Year Project Source Code\bluetooth test\data.mdb"
    db5.Open()
    strSQLCMD5 = "select * from SCHEDULE;"

    rs5.Open(strSQLCMD5, db5, 2, 2)
    rs5.AddNew()
    rs5.Fields("DATE1").Value = TextBox4.Text()
    rs5.Fields("START").Value = TextBox1.Text()
    rs5.Fields("STOP").Value = TextBox2.Text()
    rs5.Fields("REMARKS").Value = TextBox3.Text()
    rs5.Fields("CHANNEL").Value = TextBox5.Text()
    rs5.Update()
    rs5.Close()
    db5.Close()
    MsgBox("Scheduled Added Successfully")
```

[image: listboxes]

Comment: the code for the Add click event would be nice...hard to debug a picture

Comment: Reload your datasource and it will.